# Where in EthereumJ transaction signature is validated?

Tags: ethereumj, signature

I am having some troubles with finding code responsible for transaction signature verification in EthereumJ. Does anyone can point me somehow ?

I already investigated ethereumj source code but only found validation of components not the real signature against public key.

```
public static boolean validateComponents(BigInteger r, BigInteger s, byte v) {

        if (v != 27 && v != 28) return false;

        if (isLessThan(r, BigInteger.ONE)) return false;
        if (isLessThan(s, BigInteger.ONE)) return false;

        if (!isLessThan(r, Constants.getSECP256K1N())) return false;
        if (!isLessThan(s, Constants.getSECP256K1N())) return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Am I missing something ? Does such validation occurs somewhere?